# bengali fonts displaying very late in Libreoffice writer

Tags: fonts, libreoffice

I have installed a flatpack version of LibreOffice 7 in my MX Linux 19.4 KDE version since the apt version was having problems in my system. In this version of LibreOffice, Bengali words do display but with a problem. The text does not appear instantly by letter; instead, it appears as a word after pressing the spacebar. For example, suppose I am writing some text in Bengali. The words began to display after I hit the spacebar, but they don't appear before that. Here is the link to demonstrate the problem:

[Bengali font problem](https://youtu.be/VtTi0CIgJqU)

If you do not understand the language of the text written in the video, please don't stress yourself. Just notice that the letters do not appear instantly.

Comment: I must admit I don't know how Bengali text entry usually works, but isn't it sensible that the system needs to wait to know a word is finished to be sure which ligatures between letters to show? Does it happen instantly if you press [SPACE] after each word?

Comment: Yes, it happens instantly after pressing the spacebar. And it would not be sensible because the Bengali language is typed in a phonetic keyboard. So more often, you need to check which letter is being typed.

Answer (score 0):

I got your problem.

> the Bengali language is typed in a phonetic keyboard.

This is the problem. As you write in phonetic keyboard (`ibus-avro`/`openbangla-keyboard`), text doesn't go to the application. It remains in the keyboard software buffer (Try writing something, click somewhere other place to type and press space, the text is in new field (It doesn't work always)). Because it need to know what you type next. It doesn't know if k will become ক or খ (as you typed h after k). When you press a white sapce character, it commits the buffer as input. If you use a static keyboard layout (Lots are provided by `xkeyboard-config` (two Bangladeshi and many Indian) by default and lot more in `m17n-db`(Unijoy, probhat etc.)), you won't face the problem because then each key will be mapped to a single character.

But it is also a issue that rest other application show as I type though not inputted, but why your flatpak LO doesn't do so.

Comment: can you suggest some xkeyboard-config or m17n-db keyborad to type in Bengali?

Comment: Probhat is probably the most phonetic-ish static keyboard. From wikipedia, "Probhat (Bengali: প্রভাত) is a free Unicode-based Bengali fixed layout. Probhat is included in almost all Linux OS(s). Its key mapping is similar to Phonetic pattern but typing method is fully Fixed." Check the [layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bengali_input_methods#/media/File:KB-Bengali-Probhat.svg). 

You can find it in IBus Preference>Input Method>Add>...>Bangla>Bangla (Probhat)/Bangla (India, Probhat)

Comment: I don't find it in the Ibus Preferences. Is there any way to install that?

Comment: That's odd. xkeyboard-config comes with xkb of x11. You don't even need ibus to use that. But I can't find what provides it in Debian and derivatives. What other bengali layouts do you have ?

Comment: I have added the Probhat layout but don't know how to type in it. Could you please give me any guidelines? I am struggling in "JUKTOBORNO"s.

Comment: I learned how to type in the Prabhat layout. But will not the OfficeSuite applications work to fix the phonetic keymapping problem? Even Windows eradicates that problem, writing in Avro creates no issue.

Comment: @Arka Bhuiyan Check the [layout](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c2/KB-Bengali-Probhat.svg). / is ্ (হসন্ত). So ন্ত is n + / + f and such.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128483/discussion-between-arka-bhuiyan-and-ibn-fulan).